# Select the last entry of each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like the last record in each group member. but with this application, I get rather the first two entries. I feel like Max (time) does not work

```
SELECT id, latitude, longitude, MAX(temps), vitesse, description, id_recepteur
FROM donneesgps 
GROUP BY id_recepteur
```

Please help

Comment: ORDER BY      X DESC  LIMIT 2 ?   People will likely ask to see the table schema, which you can get from doing query `DESCRIBE donneesgps`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `temps` is time, you want `where`, not `group by`:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM donneesgps d
WHERE d.temps = (SELECT MAX(d2.temps)
                 FROM donneesgps d2
                 WHERE d2.id_recepteur = d.id_recepteur
                );
```